# Google Map not visible in android marshmallow(6.0)?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app, Here I am using google map. The google map shows current location to other devices but it doesn't shows current location to marshmallow(6.0).

In marshmallow(6.0) when i open the app it shows map but doesn't shows current location.

I want to show google map current location in all devices when i open an app, map has to show current location.

How do i do this ?

```
java file
public class Maps_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_ACCESS_COURSE_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    String caddress;

    //Buttons
    private ImageButton buttonSave;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
    private ImageButton buttonView;

    private Button btnProceed, btnskip, btnClocation;

    String strAdd;
    TextView tvmap,textview;

    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    public static String email;


    private ProgressDialog myProgress;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        tvmap=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_map);
        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_euser);

        //progress bar
        myProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        myProgress.setTitle("Map Loading ...");
        myProgress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        myProgress.setCancelable(true);
        // Display Progress Bar.
        myProgress.show();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //googleapi gps

    /*    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 34992, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
         locationChecker(googleApiClient, MapsActivity.this);   */

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
        btnProceed=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_proceed);
        btnskip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
        //    btnClocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clocation);

        btnProceed.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnskip.setOnClickListener(this);
        //    btnClocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
        email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
        textview.setText(email);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!enabled) {
            showDialogGPS();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void showDialogGPS() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Enable GPS");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                getCurrentLocation();
                moveMap();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btnProceed){
        //    getCurrentLocation();
        //    moveMap();
            if (loggedIn) {
                //We will start the Profile Activity

                submitForm();
                Intent i=new Intent(Maps_Activity.this,Search_ActivityND.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
        else if(v == btnskip){

            btnclick_skip();
        }

    }

    //dalete alert
    private void btnclick_skip(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you fine this Location?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        //   new JSONParserD().execute();
                        //Starting login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Maps_Activity.this, Search_ActivityND.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //    if (loggedIn) {
                        //        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Home.class);
                        //        startActivity(intent);
                        //    }

                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        //Showing the alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    //saving to database
    private void submitForm() {

        caddress = tvmap.getText().toString();
        email = textview.getText().toString();
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new MapAsync(this).execute(caddress,email);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

       if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //    tvmap.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

            strAdd = getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude);
            tvmap.setText("Current Address : " + strAdd);

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }

    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
       //String to display current latitude and longitude
        String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
        myProgress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();

        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder
                    .getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                android.location.Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                            "\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                //   Log.w("My Current loction address",
                //           "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                // Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //  Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }
  }


 manifest file

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.user.mangoair_t"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    dependencies {

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

        compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'

        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'

        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'

        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
        compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'

        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

      //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    }
```

Comment: Enable Location permission from settings

Comment: Run time permission

Comment: do you mean gps location setting?

Comment: there is a problem with the run time permission, use this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3234 for run time permission.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to check the permission at runtime for Android 6.0 or above. Here is a snippet I use to check permissions during runtime.

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
int hasCoarseLocPerm = pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
int hasFineLocPerm = pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
if (!(hasCoarseLocPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&hasFineLocPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            // do stuff
            Toast.makeText(PreferencesActivity.this, "Please provide all the permissions required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `targetSDK` is 23, you have to check **Location** permission at runtime. By default it is not granted.

In your case you should do something like this to request permission:

```
int hasLocationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (hasLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

Then result will be returned in

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {}
```

For more details please read this great tutorial of checking and request permission on Android 6.0 [New Android Runtime permission](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Comment: how do i check this location permission at run time?

Comment: follow this link  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3234 use this for run time permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for runtime permission:

```
     public void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(YourActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:Give these permission run time for marashmallow or above and put your code when permission granted**

In mainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

runtime

```
 public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10;

private String[] permissions= new String[]{
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};


if (checkPermissions())
      //  permissions  granted.    
}

private  boolean checkPermissions() {
    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p:permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```